# Why is a mosquito feeding on human blood not a parasite?

Tags: entomology, ecology, terminology

I recently read in my Ecology course notes that a mosquito feeding on human blood is not considered as a parasite. However, since it sucks blood from the human body, shouldn't it be regarded as a parasite, just like lice and ticks?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @another'Homosapien' While its understandable that OP should do some research before posting a question, I still feel we should encourage new and interesting questions as our Biology SE needs much more questions (given how vast Life Sciences are!)

Comment: @talhairfan I have no problem with the question as well as your point. But we must also not forget the website policy. The same question, with some prior research, would be a nice hit...

Comment: How is the mosquito feeding on blood different from the lion that kills its prey?

Comment: not killing prey/reducing its fitness to zero (see my comment on the accepted answer)

Comment: female mosquito , indeed is considered as a parasite and it comes under the category of _temporary_ parasite.

Comment: Its not considered a parasite

Comment: @JM97: reference please?

Comment: @BenBolker http://learning.uonbi.ac.ke/courses/SZL310/scormPackages/path_2/lecture_5__categories_of_parasites_and_hosts.html

Comment: OK, thanks. FWIW "Temporary parasites are often referred to as micropredators" (which links with Lafferty and Kuris).  Obviously there is a variety of terminology circulating, depending on sub-field ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**A mosquito is a biological parasite, it is not a medical parasite.**

There are two definitions of parasite. A biological/ecological definition and a medical/physiological interaction definition.

- A **parasite in biological terms** is an organism that benefits from a parasitic relationship; a parasitic relationship being a non-mutual relationship between species, in which one species benefits at the expense of the other. Generally the host is not killed by a small number of parasites. When the host is killed the organism is usually called predator or parasitoid.
- A **parasite in medical terms** is an organism that lives on or in a host and gets food from or at the expense of its host.

The difference is small but important; only the medical definition requires the parasite to live in or on the host for prolonged periods. It is a much narrower definition.

Biologically, a female mosquito is an indirect ectoparasite, it can be facultative or obligate depending on the species. It harms its host to benefit itself, that is all that is needed to be a parasite by the biological/ecological definition. And just like a leech or vampire bat it is hemophagic and leaves the host as soon as it is done feeding. [Brood parasites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brood_parasite) are another great example of a biological parasite that does not live on or in the host. So a cuckoo would be a biological parasite but not a medical parasite. When you consider the function and practice of medical science the more narrow definition makes sense, they are not concerned with parasites that are not going to stick around or not affect the host organism's physiology directly. By the narrower medical definition, none of these organisms are parasites even though by the biological/ecological definition they are.

Consider the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism) or a paper on [parasite evolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4413784/) vs say the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/) to see the difference.

Comment: I've read in several books which considered mosquito as parasite. (but don't know why... because mosquito does not live on/in human body). If I find the sources or some similar sources, I'll mention.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are saying that a mosquito is a parasite and consequently that the OPs "Ecology course notes" are incorrect? @AlwaysConfused John's answer would appear to state that a mosquito is a parasite "in biological terms".

Comment: Correct, which is not surprising the quality of textbooks vary widely, especially with things that have two or more discipline based definitions like this. Plus one thing you learn about biology as you advance is that there is a lot of gray area since living things dont care about our attempts to categorize them or the imprecise language we have to use to do so. JayCkat points one our very nicely, what constitutes "harm".

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Biological definitions of behavior are more like blurry venn diagrams than exclusive boxes.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer**
Female<sup>*</sup> mosquitoes are generally not to be considered ectoparasites because they spend so little time with the host. Instead, they are sometimes classified as micro-predators.

<sup>*Male mozzies don't practice [**hematophagy**](https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/hematophagy.htm) at all</sup>

**Background**
According to some sources, the term *parasite* hinges on the *time* the parasite spends on, or in its host and hence it is a gray area whether a mosquito is considered a parasite or not.

The **[CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/about.html)**, a renowned center on disease control & prevention, states the following:

> Although the term **ectoparasites** can broadly include blood-sucking arthropods such as [female] mosquitoes (because they are dependent on a blood meal from a human host for their survival), this term is **generally used more narrowly** to refer to organisms such as ticks, fleas, lice, and mites that attach or burrow into the skin and **remain there for relatively long periods of time** (e.g., weeks to months).

In contrast, female mosquitoes need only about [4 minutes](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/08/06/heres-what-happens-inside-you-when-a-mosquito-bites/) to finish their drink.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito), being explicitly not my favorite source of information, says on their [Mosquito page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito):

> Females of most species are [ectoparasites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism#Types)...

But then, when clicking through to the [Ectoparasite Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism#Types) no mention of mozzies are made and the more accepted parasitic arthropods are discussed, namely the ones stated above by the CDC (lice, ticks and fleas).

However, as mentioned in the comments below, with credits to Fileunderwater, other sources like this veterinary work on [Ectoparasites](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0632056185.html) also discusses mosquitoes.

Hence it seems to be a gray area whether mozzies are classified as (ecto)parasites. Personally, I would stick to the careful definitions provided by credible sources like the CDC - **mozzies are not considered ectoparasites**, because they spend just a few minutes siphoning blood before they are off again.

But then, as rightfully probed in the comments, what *are* they then if not parasites?

One classification I've found for insects practicing hematophagy for short periods at a time is

> **Micro-predator**: a temporary parasite (source: [English Encyclopedia](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Micro-predator));

or

> **Micro-predator**: *e.g.*, the mosquito, that derives elements essential for its existence
>   from other species of organisms, larger than itself, without causing
>   their destruction (source: [Medical Dictionary](http://medicine.academic.ru/140652/micropredator)).

Comment: Then what is the relationship between mosquito and the animals it sucks blokd from called? There's gotta be a name for something with that much significance (eg. spreading of diseases).

Comment: @hyde,very good question and I looked for it too, but to no avail. Above the term 'grazer" is brought up. I couldn't verify it's use, but it sounds quite apt :-)

Comment: in this context (disease transmission) a mosquito is called a *vector* and the animal sucked from is called a *host*

Comment: @BenBolker afaik, a mozzie is only a vector when talking about the transmission of diseases carried by them such as the malaria parasite. Outside of disease transmission they are not a vector

Comment: I agree, it depends which aspect of the relationship you're talking about. In the ecological/evolutionary context "grazer" is indeed the most common term, e.g. see http://bit.ly/2oPhlRa . Lafferty and Kuris use "micropredator", but in my experience that's less common.

Comment: I is quite easy to find other examples from "credible sources" where mosquitos are called *ectoparasites*, outside of Wikipedia; see e.g. ["*Veterinary Ectoparasites: Biology, Pathology and Control*"](https://books.google.se/books?id=xJrbivF54u0C&lpg=PA110&ots=Fh_pon1ydl&dq=female%20mosquito%20ectoparasite&hl=sv&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=mosquito&f=false)

Comment: @fileunderwater - thanks for that. I might have to rephrase my answer and stress the grayness of the matter. Thanks.

Comment: For the record, I find the CDC criteria for determining parasitism (time period used) quite silly, as a way to define ecological interactions.

Comment: @fileunderwater - you may be right and thanks for your comments here. I mentioned your source in my answer now. It is definitely a gray area. However, when I think of ectoparasites I think more of lice, fleas and ticks but that may indeed be a personal bias. I think John's answer matches your view better.

Comment: The CDC don't seem very consistent to me re: being used as a reliable source for definitions; they still define [bedbugs](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/bedbugs/faqs.html) as parasites on their own webpage, even though their own definition shouldn't agree with this. To me, mosquitoes and bedbugs are obvious parallels - they both rely on bloodmeals, but only stay in proximity to their hosts for occational access and do not live on the host(s).

Comment: Mozzie means mosquito? how funny slang :P

Comment: @AlwaysConfused - It's Ozzie slang for mosquito, yes :)

Comment: Micro -predator and parasitoid are both areas where parasite and predator overlap.

Answer (score 7):

To be a parasite, an organism needs to fulfill two criteria

1) It needs to have a non-mutual relationship between itself and its host. 
The organism derives benefit and the host suffers harm.

2)The organism also needs to live in or on their host for an extended period.

Often, a parasite will also have biological specialization to mediate the relationship between itself and its host.

However in reality, there is a spectrum of relationship. So a parasitism is not always very clear cut. How much "harm" is needed to be harmful enough? How long does a relationship need to be?

In your example the first criterion is fulfilled, but the second is not. The mosquito benefits from the blood meal and the host mammal does not. However, only female mosquitoes feed on blood and only when they are about to lay eggs. A mosquito does not spend most of its life in or around its host.

So by definition a mosquito is not a parasite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism

Comment: Your own source does not agree with your definition.

Comment: another ref: https://parasiteecology.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/predator-vs-parasite-vs-parasitoid/ Lafferty and Kuris would call mosquitos "micropredators", another commonly used term is "grazer"

Comment: The reference to the wiki page is indeed off as it explicitly counter argues your answer..

Comment: I also disagree with this answer -1

Comment: Additionally, not benefiting from something does not imply harming *per se*.

Comment: Where does Wikipedia disagree? "Unlike predators, parasites typically do not kill their host, are generally much smaller than their host, *and will often live in or on their host for an extended period*."

Comment: @BenBolker “will often” is very distinct from “always do by definition”

Comment: Don't know is it a "wrong" answer. Actually in our school-level biology we've been taught strictly as the condition to count as parasite is to simultaneously 1. dependence for food and 2. dependence for habitat . At college level I've seen some sources quite unclearly wrote mosquito as a parasite.

Comment: A flea would be an ectoparacite because both male and female fleas feed and spends their entire life cycle on its host. As for a mosquito.. only the female has blood meals and only when they are laying eggs. It is a very specific part of its life cycle, and only one sex. A vampire bat in contrast... both genders feeds on bloods and it does so as a normal part of its diet.

Comment: @BenBolker Looks like I was beaten to it but I would agree Lafferty and Kuris is the key source here - why don't you write their explanation up as an answer? I would myself but apparently my laptop battery is about to die :(